# Return custom error message when user not enabled

Tags: rest, symfony, authentication, fosuserbundle

I have been creating a web application using Symfony(FosUsersBundle) & Angular, when the user types false login informations, even when the user not enabled I always the the same response:

```
{code: 401, message: "Bad credentials"}
```

I want to retun the message "not enabled" when the user not enabled.

security.yml

```
      firewalls:
        api:
         pattern: ^/api
         stateless: true
         lexik_jwt:
            authorization_header:
                enabled: true
                prefix: Bearer
            query_parameter:
                enabled: true
                name: bearer
            throw_exceptions: false
            create_entry_point: true
         login:
            pattern: ^/login
            provider: fos_userbundle
            stateless: true
            form_login:
                check_path: /login_check
                username_parameter: username
                password_parameter: password
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
                require_previous_session: false
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your firewall configuration seems off. `pattern: ^/login` will make it work only for routes starting with /login. As soon as you navigate away from login (or login_check) your firewall will no longer work.

Apart from that, I haven't used FOSUserBundle in a while, but you probably need a [GuardAuthenticator](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html#step-2-create-the-authenticator-class). You can probably decorate the existing authenticator and only change the onFailure-function as needed. The used authenticator should be shown on /_profiler/<hash> under security.

Comment: Thanks dbrumann for your answer but I'm searching for a solution without creating my GuardAuthenticator

Comment: You could write an EventListener that listens to the `AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE`-event from the [AuthenticationFailureHandler](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/master/Security/Http/Authentication/AuthenticationFailureHandler.php#L40). You have to make sure your listener is called before another one creates a response. You can check which other listeners check for this event and which priority they have with `bin/console debug:event-dispatcher <event-name>`